# c# = operator problem

Tags: c#, operators

In C#, I have a simple 3D vector class.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Vector3D a, b;
    a = new Vector3D(0, 5, 10);
    b = new Vector3D(0, 0, 0);

    b = a;
    a.x = 10;

    Console.WriteLine("vector a=" + a.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("vector b=" + b.ToString());
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

the output is,

vector a= 10, 5, 10

vector b= 10, 5, 10

I assign a before i change a.x to 10. So i was expecting

vector a= 10, 5, 10

vector b= 0, 5, 10

From what i understand = operator assigns a reference to object like a pointer?
And in C# i cant overload = operator.

Do i have to manually assign each property?

Comment: The best practice here would be to make an *immutable* type, either a reference type or a value type, doesn't matter. Vectors are logically *values*. When you add four to twelve you don't logically "mutate" the two into a six and keep the one the same! You make a whole new number entirely. Similarly when you change the x coordinate of a vector, you don't change the x coordinate and keep y and z the same: you make a whole new vector. You'll find that you are much better able to reason about vector math if you treat values as values, not as mutable state.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, because Vecor3D is a *class* this is quite correct.

Classes are reference types and your `b = a;` statement does not copy a Vector3D instance but a reference to an instance.

If you want to 'clone' the instances, you could add the IClonable interface, but that is more or less abandoned.

A better solution for an `<X,Y,Z>` type might be to make it a struct. Structs are values types and the meaning of `b = a;` would change (towards what you want).

A 3D point meets all the criteria for a struct (small, no identity). The preferred way is to design it as immutable.

Comment: @Kayhano: If you want it to be a class, yes. But see the last version, best idea is to make it a struct.

Comment: @Kayhano, or you can change your Vector3D class to a struct (the last line of Henk's answer).

Answer (score 2):

You may want to change your `Vector3D` class to a struct.  That would let you work with a value type instead of a reference type.

Your other option is to implement `ICloneable` or use some other method to create a deep copy of your object.

Comment: Arent the Vector types in XNA all `struct`?

Comment: @Allen : I haven't played with XNA at all, so I couldn't tell you.  My guess would be that they are, however.

Comment: yep, they are :) 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb196942(v=XNAGameStudio.40).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Yes, "*= operator assigns a reference to object like a pointer*", as you put it. Thus, both `a` and `b` reference the same *single* object in memory. (The object previously referenced by `b` is not referenced any more and will be garbage collected.)

There are multiple ways to overcome this problem:

1. Make `Vector3D` a [struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/struct) instead of a class. Structs are *value* types instead of reference types, so `b = a` *copies* the contents of `a` to variable `b`.
2. Implement a `Clone` method in your `Vector3D` class (previously, this would mean implementing `ICloneable`, but [this is no longer recommended](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/brada/implementing-icloneable)). Alternatively, you could create a `Vector3D` constructor that takes another vector as a parameter and creates a copy.
3. Manually copy the three values yourself (`b = new Vector3D(a.x, a.y, a.z)`), if you cannot change the implementation of `Vector3D`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, reference types are assinged by reference.

If you want to have a separate instance, you want to **CLONE** your instance.

Create a Vector3D.Clone() method, which would look something like this:

```
public Vector3D Clone()
{
    return new Vector3D(this.x, this.y, this.x);
}
```

Then your Main should look like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Vector3D a, b;
    a = new Vector3D(0, 5, 10);
    b = new Vector3D(0, 0, 0);

    b = a.Clone();
    a.x = 10;

    Console.WriteLine("vector a=" + a.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("vector b=" + b.ToString());
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

But as others have said, something as small as a Vector3D would be better suited as an immutable struct

Answer (score 1):

You can make it a struct like Henk says.  And you can add a constructor

```
struct Vector3D
{
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public int z;

    public Vector3D(int x, int y, int z)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}", x, y, z);
    }
}
```

You could also do this without adding the constructor.

```
b = new Vector3D() {x=0, y=0, z=0};
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use a `struct`, I suggest you should design your `Vector3D` as an *immutable* class. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/897455/best-way-of-implementing-these-3-classes-in-c-vector-direction-unit-vector) are some good examples. Of course, `a.x = 10` won't be possible for an immutable class.