# Reason to make Point3D a reference type deriving from Point2D and implementing an IPoint3D interface?

Tags: c#

Apologies if this is better for the Code Review stack exchange, but I figured since this question isn't really about the code specifically, but more about the conceptual difference between reference and value types, it seemed better here.

Searching gave me this slightly related question: [Best Way of Implementing these 3 classes in C#: Vector, Direction (unit vector), Point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/897455/best-way-of-implementing-these-3-classes-in-c-vector-direction-unit-vector) -- but it's not quite it. On the other hand, searching for 'reference vs value types' gives answers that are too broad.

Recently I've started working in a new C# codebase. There's lots of existing code, and among it the following:

```
public interface IPoint2D
{
    double X { get; set; }
    double Y { get; set; }
}

public interface IPoint3D : IPoint2D
{
    double Z { get; set; }
}

public class Point2D : IPoint2D
{
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }

    // ...additional methods ommitted...
}

public class Point3D : Point2D, IPoint3D
{
    public double Z { get; set; }

    // ...additional methods ommitted...
}
```

In case it matters, the interface is defined in one assembly, the implementation in another.

This struck me as odd, for at least the following reasons:

- Does a type as fundamental as a 2- or 3-dimensional coordinate need its implementation hidden behind an interface? I suppose it permits implementing the Carthesian interface using polar or spherical coordinates (e.g., you could have `RoThetaPoint2D` implement `IPoint2D`), but I cannot recall the last time I wanted such a coordinate system difference hidden behind an interface.
- It appears to me that `IPoint3D` extending `IPoint2D` and `Point3D` deriving from `Point2D` violates the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) (though I suppose in certain projective geometries one could argue that a 3D point 'is-a' 2D point).
- Using reference types has performance implications, especially when using large arrays of points.
- `System.Tuple<float, float, float>` notwithstanding (and even that BCL design decision hasn't been without controversy as far as I know), I've never seen a managed codebase where a scalar triplet is considered a reference type. WinForms, WPF, XNA, SharpDX, and the new System.Numerics, they all use value types to represent Point, Vector, Size, Rect, etc.

Then again, while typing this up I stumbled upon [`system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.point3d`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.point3d.aspx), which is a class (i.e., a reference type) -- I imagine I could fine more examples.

My question is; **what are good reasons for coding 2- and 3-dimensional point/vector types the way it's been done above?**

Because right now I'm worried my response to the existing design is a bit knee-jerky, and based solely on: "*I've never seen anybody else do it that way.*" and "*It's gonna hurt performance.*". That seems a little weak -- I could well be overlooking some great reasons for doing things this way, and I'm all ears.

Comment: Why not have a class that can handle *any* number of dimensions, and perform all vector operations with loops instead of hard-coded operations, i.e `var vec = new Vector(dimension: 3); vec.values[0] = 1...`

Comment: Couple things: search for "mutable structs are evil" -that should give you another reference point assuming one wanted `{get;set;}`; sizeof(double) *3 = 8 * 3 = 24 which is above 16 - see [guidance for choosing using value types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229017%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Good points Alexei -- you nailed it with the `{get;set;}` thing. I'd actually make `Point3D` immutable with `public readonly float x;` (etc. for Y, and Z). Or rather yet, use the `Vector3` type in the new `System.Numerics` package, which would also alleviate the 16 byte concern somewhat (with judicious applied SIMD knowledge -- i.e., knowing where it will and won't work.).

Answer (score 1):

This is an opinionated question and well, here is an opinionated answer...

That is way too much abstraction and interfacing for something so simple.  I would simply have immutable vector types of what I need.

Even if the Vector3 changes constantly, you are doing this:

```
ObjectA.Vector3 = SomeTransformationFunction(ObjectA.Vector3);
```

Vector3 could totally be an immutable type here.  I am having a very difficult time finding a scenario in which a mutable type that described a vector was better and therefor would say that if in doubt, go as simple as possible.